# Power Query showing data that cant be filtered nor can be found while merging while some values in the column are working properly

Tags: powerbi, filtering, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

in power query I have data ROE = 23,85 but when I actually trying to filter this value it says this value doesnt exist neither it can be found within merging functions.

The situation is printscreened in following:
[image: DATA]
[image: Result after filtering the ROE]

Everything is refreshed, uploaded...

The data source is from SQL table - can it be any problem there? (But some other numbers in the same column are showing (filtering and mergind) correctly, no pattern.

Dropdown option with multiple rows looks:
[image: Dropdown]
[image: Dropdown1]
[image: Dropdown2]

If M Code would help, here it is:

```
    let
    Source = Sql.Database("xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"),
    stage_onecore_RoeCalculation = Source{[Schema="stage_onecore",Item="RoeCalculation"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(stage_onecore_RoeCalculation,{"Contract No_", "Entry No_", "ROE _"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Contract No_"}, {{"MinEntryNo", each List.Min([Entry No_]), Int64.Type}, {"All", each _, type table [Contract No_=nullable text, Entry No_=nullable number, ROE _=nullable number]}}),
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Entry No_", "ROE _"}, {"Entry No_", "ROE _"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded All", each ([Entry No_] = [MinEntryNo])),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"ROE _", "ROE %"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each ([Contract No_] = "12187012" or [Contract No_] = "15761011" or [Contract No_] = "1100000064") and ([#"ROE %"] = 23.93))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

so i tried to do a SQL:

```
SELECT
  [Contract No_],
  [Entry No_],
  [ROE _]
FROM
  stage_onecore.RoeCalculation
WHERE
  [Entry No_] IN (
    SELECT
      MIN([Entry No_])
    FROM
      stage_onecore.RoeCalculation
    GROUP BY
      [Contract No_]
  )
```

and if iam doing it from power bi or excel it doesnt work without any other changes/steps... It seems if I would group it it works fine but after the grouping some numbers doesnt work...

Comment: Try using the drop down arrow at the top right of ROE % column to apply the filter by placing an [x] next to the value you are filtering for. See what code is generated.  You can also edit your question to paste in your code that you obtain from home...advanced editor... for additional help

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am enclosing the dropdown option with printscreens - also doesnt work.

Comment: why are you filtering on contract number? What happens if you just filter ROE?

Comment: some numbers are showing correctly therefore Iam looking at another table where I see which numbers doesnt match with merging and then I just filter the examples with the contract no, those no cant be seen while filtering nor the merging

Comment: if the data is properly refreshed and you use the dropdown to filter, there should be no reason that row does not show up.  To make sure the data is refreshed you could copy the code into a second query and see if it works there

Comment: Well I dont see any reason neither. Copying to a different query results in same outcome.

Comment: Sorry, I have no further ideas. Perhaps someone else can help

Comment: Try with 23,93 instead of 23.93

Comment: Tried that as well. :) Thank you but that also doesnt work.

Comment: how about and (Number.IntegerDivide([#"ROE %"]*100, 1) = 2393))

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the values you show in your screenshot. For better assistance I suggest you post something that will allow us to reproduce your problem. M-Code as text that **reproduces** the problem would be most helpful. Your posted M-Code does not include the data, so is not really helpful.

Comment: I think its impossible to reproduce the problem... Those are normal numbers...

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem, then just re-do your query and it will be fine.

Comment: creating calculated column works with those numbers and also the new column can be filtered but this is not normal :D

Comment: I tried to copy this query to excel and it is the same. Can it be some corrupted data from source SQL table?

Comment: Without my being able to reproduce your problem here, it is not possible for me to comment on the cause.

Comment: so i tried to do a SQL:
SELECT
  [Contract No_],
  [Entry No_],
  [ROE _]
FROM
  stage_onecore.RoeCalculation
WHERE
  [Entry No_] IN (
    SELECT
      MIN([Entry No_])
    FROM
      stage_onecore.RoeCalculation
    GROUP BY
      [Contract No_]
  )
and if iam doing it from power bi or excel it doesnt work without any other changes/steps... It seems if I would group it it works fine but after the grouping some numbers doesnt work...